# Showing title keyword in autocomplete

Tags: search

I have just installed search auto complete module,its working fine,but the problem is its showing title before every result like:

title: Drupal 7.9 Release

tile:Understanding Drupal

Here Drupal 7.9 release and Understanding Drupal are my article title may be due to that its showing,but anyhow i want to remove this.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's by design; the name of the field that the result is for is displayed before the result itself. See the `_search_autocomplete_render_multiple_field()` and `_search_autocomplete_render_fields()` functions in the search_autocomplete.view_autocomplete.inc file. It's probably possible to override those but I'm not sure how Search Autocomplete is implemented

Answer (score 0):

In search_autocomplete.view_autocomplete.inc file, line number 209 just replace it with the following line:

$object->label .= ' ';

that will remove the label (title) in search result.